# partial matching in django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

suppose, i'v an username (**abcde**). now if i search for **abcd** or **bcde** it should return that object which username is **abcde**. How to do that?

```
#filters.py
from .models import User
import django_filters

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']
```

```
#views.py
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def search(request):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    filterset = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
    if filterset.is_valid():
         queryset = filterset.qs
    serializer = SimpleUserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: queryset = User.objects.filter(username__contains='abcd')

Answer (score 3):

the `contains` or `icontains` filter:

```py
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'username': 'icontains'
        }
```